# How to get source code from apk file in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have loss my important android project and their files also in mac osx pc. I have only .apk file of that project.Can some one tell me how to getting source from apk because i can not create big project again and it's urgent.Please someone help me or guid me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a Look This But Not Geaing All Source Code From Apk File

[decompile apk file android](http://www.decompileandroid.com/)

Comment: I have download apktool but what is command line on mac pc in terminal.

Comment: App tool is Also Work But Now That Good Way do decompile apk